# galleria auto play slideshow?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, galleria

Has anyone found an easy way to get the awesome galleria gallery to auto play?

I'm really stuck on this one.

Any help would be great!

Thx Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    extend: function() {
        this.play(4000); // will advance every 4th second
    }
});
```

No longer works with the latest version. See below.

Answer (score 4):

autoplay: true 
in the options should do the trick.

> autoplay
>
> ```
> type: Boolean or Number
> default: false
> ```
>
> If true, this will start playing the
>   slideshow with 3 seconds interval
>   (default). If you set this to any
>   number, f.ex 4000, it will start
>   playing with that interval (in
>   milliseconds)

My problem is that once it's started, it does not stop when a photo or thumb is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of galleria has a new way to implement this and I do not believe it is automatically going to scroll unless you implicitly force it to with a setting now.

Also, the issue with the autoplay not stopping after a click is now fixed in the latest version.

```
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('../include/scripts/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.run('#galleria', {
    transition: 'fade',
    imageCrop: true,
    autoplay: 2500 // will move forward every 7 seconds
});          
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to below documentation, by default you should be getting the behavior you are looking for. Try setting it explicitly.

pauseOnInteraction
type: Boolean
default: true
During playback, Galleria will stop the playback if the user presses thumbnails or any other navigational links. If you dont want this behaviour, set this option to false.