# Anyone know how to use the jQuery Gallery View Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the [jQuery Gallery View plugin](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) because I was looking for a good way to cycle through pictures including text and one that was well designed. This plugin does not seem to be updated anymore and does not have much documentation so I am having difficulties implementing it. Does anyone have an idea as to how it works?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Heres the code I have now (of course with the pictures at the right locations just not possible to attach in jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/GgusY/

Comment: If it's not updated any more, then perhaps you might like to choose another jQuery plugin which is. jQuery is under pretty much constant development and improvement. At any rate, a glance at the website you linked shows what looks to me like sufficient documentation. Maybe you'd like to post a http://jsfiddle.net of what you have so far?

Comment: jquery fancybox ftw - it does galleries in a nice light box. All you need to do is setup a nice grid structure. http://fancybox.net/

Comment: I have tried its just this one looks great and does exactly what my client wants, they don't like the other plugins I come up with.

Comment: @Jason, I don't need a lightbox, What I am really looking for is something that will deal with pictures and text in a flashish manner using javascript. This is all I could find that would do it like the client wants.

Comment: o, sorry didn't noticed you lengthened your post, will do.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/GgusY/

Comment: Kind of hard to test without actual photos; also, it looks like you didn't include jQuery, the plugin, or the required CSS. I'm going to see what I can do with the fiddle...

Comment: yeah, on the website I had all those, I am putting those over right now, I just found a website of a person who got it to work recently so I am seeing if that is any help, thanks so much!

Comment: just added pics and the js and css files and it doesn't seem to have changed it a ton: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/GgusY/1/

Comment: oh, yeah, thats not very good, I will try to fix this... the problem is that I am trying to get this working for my sister who does not know web development at all because she was trying to do this before. The code is mostly hers that she did copy and pasting with.

Comment: Are you using an old version of jquery gallery. Here's my version, probably would work fine it there was images - http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/GgusY/

Comment: yeah, no I'm using the latest, probably another problem on my end, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a start](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Q6sjM/1/).

I'm taking a total guess at what your markup is supposed to be, because you were missing a bunch of `</div>` (close div) tags.

Things I had to change to get it this far:

1. Download [`galleryview-2.1.1.zip`](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/7317/release), and from that file...
2. Paste in contents of `galleryview.css` and `jquery.galleryview-2.1.1js` into the fiddle (normally you'd do this with proper external scripts and stylesheets)
3. Fix the markup so that all those `<div class="panel">` tags are properly closed
4. Get a copy of `jquery.timers-1.1.2.js` onto the page

---

[Step 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Q6sjM/1/): got the loader image working by hosting the `loader.gif` file on [imgur](http://imgur.com) and editing the CSS accordingly.

Themes are tougher, because apparently, this genius™ plugin tries to figure out where your themes are hosted based on the location of the `<script>` tag which was used to load the galleryview plugin code. Absolute *genius*... `</sarcasm>`

---

#### [Check it out →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Q6sjM/2/)

no more image 404s. Loaded `next.gif`, `prev.gif`, `panel-nav-next.gif`, and `panel-nav-prev.gif` onto imgur so that jsfiddle can actually get the images.

I had to actually edit the plugin source for this one; if your server has the directory structure that galleryview expects, **this should not be necessary**.

---

### Now here's the thing

You could keep wrestling with this plugin.

Or, you could use a different one, like [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/). As far as I can tell from the example you've been trying to assemble, Galleria does all the same stuff. Since Galleria is [actively](http://twitter.com/#!/galleriajs) [maintained](https://github.com/aino/galleria), you should actually be able to use it with a reasonably recent version of jQuery, as well as **actually get support for it from the developer.**

Comment: thank you very much, I think I will probably look around again to see if I can find anything else. The problem with Galleria is that I need it to run automatically

Comment: @chrome: if I understand your requirements correctly, [you can actually do this with Galleria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845312/galleria-auto-play-slideshow).

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest version of jquery gallery view here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/7317/release

Then following on from that:
http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/GgusY/

`$('#photos .filmstrip').galleryView({
              panel_width: 800,

              panel_height: 300,

              frame_width: 100,

              frame_height: 100
            });`

Comment: You keep linking the same fiddle as what the OP posted originally.

Comment: damn you fiddle. okay ignore the fiddle, just include the latest version. run it like i've shown above